# Permutation /Combination

Tags: statistics

There are three different types of note book in a bin. 100 type A, 100 type B, 100 type C. How many different way I can pick 3 notebook one of each. ( where order does not matter.)

I did this way

(300)(200)(100)/ (100*100*100)= 6
But the answer is 10.

can anybody help me?

Comment: $6$?  Surely the answer is $100^3=10^6$.  I can't follow your calculation.

Comment: The answer says  10.

Comment: Are the notebooks of a single type distinguishable?  The answer in my comment assumed they were.  But if they aren't, then why isn't the answer just $1$?  After all, you need one of type $A$, one of type $B$, one of type $C$.  What else is there to say?

Comment: Please write out the question exactly as it appears.

Comment: yes, first  I was also thinking the same way as you describe.  but think about when I choose the first one I have 3 option, then for the second one I have 2 option then for the third , I have one option.

Comment: You said the order didn't matter.

Comment: yes, order does not matter. And the question is exactly same in the Paper. It was in a ACT test.

Comment: Well, even trying to be flexible with the language I can't reverse engineer the answer $10$.  Maybe someone else can?

Comment: Oh, hold on:  I was reading the "one of each type" to mean that you wanted one of each type.  Not sure how else it could be read.  But if you just ignore that then I do get the answer $10$.

Comment: yes one of each . can you show me.

Comment: The $10$ ways are:  there are three ways if you just pick all of one type.  If you pick two types then there are $3$ choices for the two and $2$ for the one, so $6$.  And there is $1$ way to pick all three types.  So:  $10=3+6+1$.

Comment: Like I say, I am ignoring the "one of each".  I can't see how else to get $10$.

Comment: that makes sense.  Probably they used the word to confuse. Thank you

Comment: I think @ lulu is right: the answer is $100^3.$ Looking at in another way, the probability of getting three different types is $100^3/{300\choose 3}$ or $(300/300)(200/299)(100/298).$ Either way  0.2244619. // In R, taking `bin = rep(1:3, each=100` and sampling from a fresh bin a million times with`x = replicate(10^6, length(unique(sample(bin, 3))))`, the proportion `mean(x==3)` returns `0.224097`. This agrees with the exact probability to three places, as one would expect from a million iterations. [Respective probs of drawing exactly 1 and exactly 2 types are aprx `0.108826, 0.667077`.]

Comment: The word "one of each" has to be omitted. I used it wrongly. @BruceET, the problem is not for probability. It is counting principle. And as it says order does not matter. So lulu's answer is right. all possible arrangements can be  AAA, BBB, CCC, ABB, ACC, BAA,BCC, CAA, CBB, ABC. The total no of possible way is 10.

Answer (score 0):

we have 100 books in each type. (i.e) Type A,Type B,Type C.

**If each book is different from other books**
Then each type has $100$ different books. I am going to choose one book from each type (and by your given data order of the chosen books is not a matter).
The total number of possibilities = $100*100*100=1000000$

**If all the books in type A,B and C is  identical**

Then choosing any book in Type A yields the same book due to identical.
I am going to choose one book from each type (and by your given data order of the chosen books is not a matter)
The total number of possiblities=$1*1*1=1$.